# Is this an $E_\infty$-algebra?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, operads, higher-algebra

I have a particular kind of algebraic structure that's come up in my work. It's basically a chain complex equipped with a multiplication which is commutative and associative up to homotopy in a particularly nice way. So one might hope that it's some variation of an $E_\infty$-algebra. Unfortunately I cannot see a direct relation between the two notions.

Fix a ground ring $R$. (Everything below will make sense more generally than for $R$-modules, though.) Let $A$ be a left module over the commutative operad, a.k.a. a twisted commutative algebra, in the category of dg $R$-modules. We suppose that $A(0)=0$.

To be explicit, this means that I have a sequence $\{A(n)\}_{n \geq 1}$ of chain complexes over $R$ with actions of the symmetric groups $S_n$, and a multiplication map $A(m) \otimes A(n) \to A(m+n)$ which is $S_m \times S_n$-equivariant. I impose also the condition that the multiplication is associative,  and that it's commutative in a "twisted" sense, meaning that the diagram 
$$ A(m) \otimes A(n) \to A(m+n) $$
$$ \cong \hspace{6em}\cong$$
$$ A(n) \otimes A(m) \to A(n+m) $$
commutes. Here the left vertical isomorphism is the "flip" map, and the right isomorphism is acting by the "box" permutation $(n+1,n+2,...,n+m,1,2,\ldots,n)$.

So far I'm only repeating standard definitions. Let me define $A$ to be a **homotopy twisted commutative algebra** if it is moreover equipped with an element $\mathbf 1 \in A(1)$ such that multiplication with $\mathbf 1$ induces a quasi-isomorphism $A(n) \to A(n+1)$ for all $n$.

*Example*. If $C$ is a unital commutative algebra over $R$ in the usual sense, then if I put $A(n)=C$ with trivial $S_n$-action, with multiplication given by the usual multiplication in $C$, then I obtain a rather trivial example of a homotopy twisted commutative algebra.

*Claim*. If $A$ has vanishing differential, then it is necessarily of the form of the previous example. Indeed multiplication by $\mathbf 1$ gives me *isomorphisms* $A(n) \cong A(n+1)$  which I can use the to identify all the different components; one can prove that under these isomorphisms, the multiplication $A(1) \otimes A(1) \to A(2) \cong A(1)$ becomes on-the-nose commutative and associative.

So in general a homotopy twisted commutative algebra will on the level of cohomology give me a strictly commutative multiplication. But on the chain level I have something weaker. If I choose a quasi-inverse $A(2) \stackrel \sim \to A(1)$ I get a multiplication on $A(1)$, but now it is only commutative and associative up to homotopy.

**Question:** Is there a relationship between homotopy twisted commutative algebras and $E_\infty$-algebras? For example, is there a functor from one of them to the other? A Quillen equivalence?

Comment: Taking chains with $R$ coefficients gives a functor from the category of commutative symmetric ring spectra   to the category of $dg$ tca's equipped with an element in degree $1$ (see http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/SymSpec-v3.pdf).  Since  commutative symmetric ring spectra  can be compared to $E_\infty$ algebras,  it seems reasonable that there is a comparison that goes through symmetric spectra.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this data yields a lax symmetric monoidal functor $\mathsf{Fin}^{inj} \to \mathsf{Ch}(R)$ from the category of finite sets and injections? If so, then you get a lax symmetric monoidal functor of $\infty$-categories $\mathsf{Fin}^{inj} \to \mathsf{D}(R):= \mathsf{Ch}(R)[q.i.^{-1}]$. The homotopy colimit then naturally has the structure of an $E_{\infty}$-algebra and, in this case, that homotopy colimit is equivalent to $A(1)$, whence $A(1)$ has the structure of an $E_{\infty}$-algebra.

Comment: @Phil Sorry I'm dense - can you tell me where in Schwede's book to look?

Comment: @Dylan Thanks! That makes a lot of sense, I hadn't noticed the connection with the category $\mathsf{Fin}^{inj}$. It seems Corollary 3.7 of Sagave and Schlichtkrull's "Diagram spaces and symmetric spectra" is very close to what I hoped to be true (stated for spaces, not chain complexes).

Comment: @Dan No worries! Sorry for the vague reference. If you take the definition of commutative ring spectra in the book and apply reduced chains, then monoidality directly gives a pointed dg tca structure

Comment: Maybe these comments should be posted as answers...